# From alternating series to integral

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Consider the following alternating series
$$
S = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\cos(k\pi/n)
$$

> **My question** Is it possible to convert $S$ to an integral representation?

Of course, the problem relies on the alternating coefficients $(-1)^k$. Indeed, if $S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \cos(k\pi/n)$, it easily follows that $S=\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some change of variable : $ n\leftarrow 2m $, we get :

$ S=\lim\limits_{m\to +\infty}{\frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}}=\lim\limits_{m\to +\infty}{\left(\frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m-1}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}-\frac{1}{2m}\right)} $

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\lim\limits_{m\to +\infty}{\frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m-1}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}} $

Let $ m $ be a positive integer, we have : \begin{aligned}\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}&=\frac{1}{2m}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{m}\right)}}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{\left(2k+1\right)\pi}{2m}\right)}}\right)\\ &=\frac{1}{2m}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{m}\right)}}-\left(\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{m}\right)}}\right)\right)\\ &=\frac{1}{2m}\left(2\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{m}\right)}}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}-\sum_{k=m}^{2m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}}\right)\\ &=\frac{1}{2m}\left(2\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{m}\right)}}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{\left(m+k\right)\pi}{2m}\right)}}}\right)\\ \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1}{\left(-1\right)^{k}\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{m}\right)}}-\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\cos{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}+\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\sin{\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m}\right)}}\end{aligned}

Which means : $$ S=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\cos{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}+\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x} $$

The limit would then be $ 0 $, which in my opinion would have been much easier to prove by squeezing, or by looking for a closed form for the partial sum.